# GIT creating extraneous ~HEAD files during rebase

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

Running into an issue that I've never seen while rebasing.

I have a **master** branch that has had some bugfixes.

I have a **dev** branch that forked off of master sometime in the past, before bugfixes.

I change to the dev branch, then run:

```
git rebase master
```

It rewinds and tries to replay the dev changes.

The rebase stops, I get a conflict that I have to resolve.

I resolved a normal conflict, added the resolved file, then run:

```
git rebase --continue
```

There is another conflict, and I run:

```
git status
```

..to see the state of things.   I see some normal changes, some unmerged paths,
but then also some Untracked files that I've never seen before:

```
path/to/something/existingFileName.ext~HEAD
```

I can look back and see that these files did not exist in either branch 
at the time of the commit that we reverted to.  I'm curious about why they 
were created by the rebase process, and what, if anything I should do with them?

Comment: Did you use any particular merge tool to resolve the conflict? kdiff3? meld? Beyond Compare?

Comment: It was a command line rebase, I resolved the conflicts by editting in vi.

Answer (score 1):

These are the files it uses to reconcile the merge: yours, theirs, and the thing we both started with.  After you resolve the conflict, and run `git rebase --continue` and get done, are they still there?

Comment: I completed the rebase, but they are still there, showing as untracked files.  Very odd.

Comment: I was able to clean them up post-rebase, and it seems to have caused no problem.  Still wondering how they were created though.

Comment: I just experienced the same thing after an interactive rebase that required multiple manual conflict resolutions and involved moving / renaming files. A `foo~HEAD` file remained after `git rebase --continue` and after the rebase completed; I `rm`ed it and had no issues from there.